# How to use boost when installed via homebrew?

Tags: c++, macos, boost, homebrew

This might be a very basic question, but this is my first time with such an issue. I am using an M1 macOS Big Sur. I am trying to run boost libraries for my program. I have installed boost on my device using `arch -arm64 brew install boost`.

When I try to compile the following program:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
using namespace boost::multiprecision;
using namespace std;
 
int128_t boost_product(long long A, long long B)
{
    int128_t ans = (int128_t)A * B;
    return ans;
}
 
int main()
{
    long long first = 98745636214564698;
    long long second = 7459874565236544789;
    cout << "Product of " << first << " * " << second
         << " = \n"
         << boost_product(first, second);
    return 0;
}
```

with

```
$ g++ --version
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin20.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

I get the following error:

```
boost.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

This is what I see when I go into `/opt/homebrew/lib:`

```
cmake                                  libboost_log-mt.dylib                  libboost_serialization.a               libgettextsrc-0.21.dylib
gcc                                    libboost_log.a                         libboost_serialization.dylib           libgettextsrc.dylib
gettext                                libboost_log.dylib                     libboost_stacktrace_addr2line-mt.a     libgmp.10.dylib
libasprintf.0.dylib                    libboost_log_setup-mt.a                libboost_stacktrace_addr2line-mt.dylib libgmp.a
libasprintf.a                          libboost_log_setup-mt.dylib            libboost_stacktrace_addr2line.a        libgmp.dylib
libasprintf.dylib                      libboost_log_setup.a                   libboost_stacktrace_addr2line.dylib    libgmpxx.4.dylib
libboost_atomic-mt.a                   libboost_log_setup.dylib               libboost_stacktrace_basic-mt.a         libgmpxx.a
libboost_atomic-mt.dylib               libboost_math_c99-mt.a                 libboost_stacktrace_basic-mt.dylib     libgmpxx.dylib
...
```

When I cd into cmake, I see that there are a bunch of `Boost_...`-prefixed files.

It looks like I have boost on my computer, but how do I use it in my program and compile it with g++?

Comment: Can you find the header files on disc? I would also try eliminating the path in the include statement. If they are properly installed, the <> bracket search should be able to find them on the path.

Comment: I cannot seem to find the header files. All I see are cmake and makefiles in the /opt/homebrew/lib directory @MikelF

Comment: I got rid of the #include<path>, but I still get the same error

Comment: Hello @MikelF, I have found the boost .hpp files on disc. How would I go about linking them to the compilation?

Comment: I think by some combination of something along the lines of using `find_package()` and passing `-D CMAKE_MODULE_PATH=$(brew --prefix boost)/lib/cmake` when configuring.

Comment: You will have to add the location of those files to the header path for your toolchain. You will also need to make sure the linker path includes the location for the dynamic libraries.

Comment: Understood. I have figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that the homebrew was adding files to `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.79.0_1/include/boost`. Once the location was identified, I simply compiled by code with flag

`g++ -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.79.0_1/include/boost ...`

And made sure my include statements referenced the appropriate .hpp files.